# Why is the Camera of AreaLearning Demo Sence different from Gankino and IKariotikos Version? Is there a special reason?

Tags: google-project-tango

Hello? I am a Korean developer who is developing using the Tango Unity SDK.
I'm using the GanKino version and are now updating to the IKarioTikos version.
Is there a specific reason to use TangoCamera instead of Tango ARCamera in IKarioTikos's Demo Sence, AreaLearning?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the change has been made since Gankino's update in may 2017. If you look at [the release notes](https://developers.google.com/tango/release-notes), it says:

> SDK updates: The Tango Unity SDK now has a single TangoCamera prefab
>   that supports the TangoARCamera and TangoDeltaCamera use cases.

What I understand is that they just grouped the different prefabs they used to have (TangoARCamera, TangoDeltaCamera) into one single prefab called TangoCamera. The point is that they didn't update the examples so AreaLearning example still uses the now deprecated TangoARCamera.

Except the fact that they say it is now deprecated, I personnally have no problem of still using TangoARCamera prefab in my app. I might change when the examples and tutorials will be fully updated.

Answer (score 0):

TangoARCamera and TangoDeltaCamera have been deprecated in the latest release.  You can just use **TangoCamera** now.  Just remember to enable the **TangoARScreen** script component in order to enable AR functionality.

I've successfully built and run AR apps with TangoSDK_Ikariotikos_Unity5 on Unity 5.6.3f1 using the above approach.  Do note that initial releases of Unity 2017 does not support the Tango downloaded package so best to use 5.6.xxx