# Something about Unity SDK of Google tango project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I have some questions about Google Tango development on Unity 3D.

First, the script named Tango Application in Tango Manager perfab doesn't has Enable Area Learning option. So I don't know how to use [Unity How-to Guide: Area Learning](https://developers.google.cn/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-area-learning).

Then, I use Tango Camera prefeb to follow the guide "the motion tracking" and "the depth perception", phone screen appears double image as the phone's pose and position changes.

My unity edition is 5.2.1 f1, visual studio edition is 2017, and the JDK and the Android SDK is latest. The device is lenovo Phab 2 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the developpers have modified the prefabs in the last 2 versions of the Tango Unity SDK (Gankino and Ikariotikos).

If you look at the code of [TangoApplication.cs](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Core/Scripts/TangoWrappers/TangoApplication.cs), you will find lines 115-116:

```
[FormerlySerializedAs("m_enableADFLoading")]
public bool m_enableAreaDescriptions = false;
[FormerlySerializedAs("m_enableAreaLearning")]
public bool m_areaDescriptionLearningMode = false;
```

So it is those 2 fields that you need to use, but apparently you can't set them from the Editor anymore, you will need to set them from your code:

```
//For example like that
FindObjectOfType<TangoApplication>().m_enableAreaDescriptions = true;
```

Regarding the Camera prefab, they grouped the two prefab they used to have into one single Tango Camera prefab. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427158/why-is-the-camera-of-arealearning-demo-sence-different-from-gankino-and-ikarioti), you just need to enable the **TangoARScreen** component of the prefab to make it work properly.